# **Log-linear** scale in sns.jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, binning

I have the following code to plot the scattering plot by sns.jointplot. I need to set **logarithmic** binning and logarithmic scale for the x axis and **linear** one for the y axis. (x and y are 1D arrays)

```
bins_x =np.logspace(np.log10(min(x)) , np.log10(max(x)) , num=15)
bins_y = np.linspace (min(y), max(y), num=15)

g=sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, kind='hist', cbar=True, height=6, ratio=3, space=0.2, bins=[bins_x, bins_y])

g.ax_joint.set_xscale('log')
```

The result of the code is this plot:

[image]

The scatter plot looks ok. But the 1D histogram on top of the plot (corresponding to the x axis is not logarithmically binned).
Do you know how can I solve it? Or do you know other way to plot this graph?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26059979/7758804

Comment: I have seen that question, that is a **log-log** plot which can be easily plotted by log_scale=True. But, my question is how to plot **log-linear** plot.